# Is the hiperfifo.c example thread safe

Tags: multithreading, curl, libcurl, libevent

I see numerous references on how a curl multi handle should not be used across threads concurrently. However in the [hiperfifo.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/hiperfifo.html) example, the handle seems to be accessed concurrently from fifo_cb, timer_cb and event_cb. Is it implicit that some synchornization should be added by the curl programmer?
Or is libevent serializing the callbacks?

Answer (score 1):

libevent is serializing the callbacks. It works within a single thread.

(and the recently created canonical URL for information about libcurl's threadsafeness is: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threadsafe.html)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this.